# Paypal Express Checkout / API Issue / Error 10410

Tags: paypal

All of a sudden my site has stopped taking payments using paypal, no files have been changed but I now get this error:

Fail!
POST /2.0/ HTTP/1.1 Host: api-3t.paypal.com *Blanked out info for security*
Error 10410 - Invalid token.

I have restored site files from backups to make sure it isn't that, the last time it worked was the 9th of July.

I have confirmed API details with the paypal account and they are still the same

Is there anything else I could check? Have paypal changed anything?

Answer (score 1):

That error is pretty specific.  It simply means the TOKEN you sent with your request is invalid for one reason or another.  You need to look at your raw API request to see what you're sending for the TOKEN value.  It could be from GetExpressCheckoutDetails or it could be from DoExpressCheckoutPayment.  I can't really tell from what you've said here, but it's gotta be one of those.